# How to use typescript 4 package in typescript 3 project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, typescript-typings, jodit

I have a ReactJS project built with create-react-app with typescript template and it is using typescript v3.7.5.

```
package.json
{
  ...
      "typescript": "3.7.5",
  ...
}
```

I added the Jodit editor into my project following this [guide](https://xdsoft.net/jodit/examples/intergration/react-jodit.html).

But I am getting this error when I run the project.

```
/path/to/project/node_modules/jodit/index.d.ts
TypeScript error in /path/to/project/node_modules/jodit/index.d.ts(7,13):
'=' expected.  TS1005

     5 |  */
     6 |
  >  7 | import type { IComponent, Nullable } from './src/types';
       |             ^
     8 | import { Jodit as Super } from './src/jodit';
     9 |
    10 | export * from './src/types';
```

After getting this error, I did some investigation and found that jodit-react is built with typescript v4.1.3.

```
  "typescript": "^4.1.3",
```

Maybe we are getting the error because of this typescript version difference. I am not so familiar with typescript and I am not sure if it is correct.

Anyone who has experience in this case, please let me know what I can do to use this package in my project.

Comment: You have a two options as far as I see it: A) Update typescript to 3.8+ (this is when `import type ... from ...` and `export type ... from ...` was introduced) or B) downgrade jodit to a version that does not use `import type ... from ...`

Comment: @JacobSmit I see. I only tried to find a way to bump typescript version to 4. Btw, could you please let me know how to upgrade the typescript version?

Comment: Just like you would any other package, update the version number in package.json and then call `npm install` or your appropriate package manager command if using something else. The versions available are listed on each npm package's information page ([Typescript one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript?activeTab=versions)) any of the version numbers that appear on that page are valid. As to whats in each version you would have to look at change logs or similar to figure out what features came in where.